# How to get the full row in Database according to one column

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am working in PostGres and i have a row let's say the one below:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName        ContactName     Address         City    PostalCode  Country
  1        Alfreds Futterkiste   Maria Anders   Obere Str. 57   Berlin  12209       Germany
  2         Ana Trujillo         Emparedados    Borlo 2222      México  05021       Mexico
```

Now i have to get the entire row which contains City as `México` ?

If it was Row Number basis it was like this (very easy) :

```
select * from Customers limit RowNumber-1, 1
```

I know how to get the row on the number of row basis but i don't know how to get the row on the data of column basis (Mexico in my case) ?

**Note** please note that i have to store each column in a List of Class, I mean something like this :

```
List<Coustomer> cstmr = new List<Coustomer>() ;
```

// and do somethign like this

```
foreach(var column in cstmr)
column.CustomerName=Ana Trujillo; // in Mexico's case
column.Country=Mexico;
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ColumnName = YourValue, something like this?

Answer (score 2):

All you want is

`select * from Customers where City = 'México';`

Read this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_where_clause.htm) for more info on using WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking to put the values of row in the object of `List<Coustomer>` than

This might do the trick for you

```
private IList<Coustomer> MakeCustomers(DataTable dt)
{
    IList<Coustomer> list = new List<Coustomer>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        list.Add(MakeCustomer(row));

    return list;
}

private Customer MakeCustomer(DataRow row)
{
    int customerId = int.Parse(row["CustomerId"].ToString());
    string CustomerName = row["CustomerName"].ToString();
    string ContactName = row["ContactName"].ToString();
    string country = row["Country"].ToString();
    //Any other fields which might be pulling from DB
    return new Customer(customerId, company, city, country);
}
```